# Web Script to Filter Documents

Tags: javascript, php, web-services, sorting, web

I'm an intern working for a contractor company that receives several 80 page government contract proposals daily in the form of pdfs.  The emails containing these pdfs are sent to a specific folder within my individual company gmail account, and my task is to essentially sort them.  I'm given a list of keywords from my company to help me separate the documents based on their relevancy to the types of tasks that my company wants to complete. Initially all I want to do is separate the important pdfs from the unimportant pdfs through an automated process based on those keywords. But ultimately, I would like to be able to automate entire process, this includes: the process of opening my emails located in the specific folder, opening the link to the pdf proposal within the emails, and then finally determining whether the pdf qualifies as a good proposal for my company (which is basically phase one of the assignment). The end product will hopefully be an automated accurate list of "good" and "bad" proposals that saves my higher ups and myself loads of time.

My issue is I really have no idea where to start with this.. what language should I use to implement a script like this? And in a general sense how would this process happen? I can learn anything I need to know fairly quickly... I just need to know where to start since I've never done anything like this.

Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

I have no idea what kind of application your trying to build. But with PHP you can look at the scandir function and fopen/read/close function. If you want to read the text in the PDF you can take a look at this: http://www.phpclasses.org/browse/file/31030.html

http://php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_open.asp